# Is there a better way to insert an enum into a set without macros?

Tags: c++, enum, set

I created an `enum` for a class and in the constructor I inserted all the `enum` values into a set.  I am wondering if there is a better way anyone can recommend.  I feel like there should be, but have been unable to think of one or find one online.  I wrote the code in C++ and am using the Boost libraries.

Here is the `enum`:

```
class CreateAndUseIniFile {

    std::set<CreateAndUseIniFile::iniFileValues> m_modules;
    enum iniFileValues {
        FIXED_VOLTAGE1,
        FIXED_VOLTAGE2,
        FIXED_VOLTAGE3,
        FIXED_VOLTAGE4
    }
}
```

and this is the constructor where I add the values

```
CreateAndUseIniFile::CreateAndUseIniFile() {
    m_modules.insert(CreateAndUseIniFile::FIXED_VOLTAGE1);
    m_modules.insert(CreateAndUseIniFile::FIXED_VOLTAGE2);
    m_modules.insert(CreateAndUseIniFile::FIXED_VOLTAGE3);
    m_modules.insert(CreateAndUseIniFile::FIXED_VOLTAGE4);
}
```

Comment: Like the fellow asking http://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/35208/32004 it sounds like you might be looking for [n3815](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2013/n3815.html) to become real.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can iterate over the `enum` and insert each one individually.

```
for ( int i = FIXED_VOLTAGE1; i != FIXED_VOLTAGE4; i++ )
{
    m_modules.insert(CreateAndUseIniFile::static_cast<iniFileValues>(i));
}
```

**Note**: This will work with your specific case... don't do this if you have `enums` with set values that contain gaps between `enum` values.

Comment: Thanks, for some reason I thought I couldn't iterate though an enum

Comment: @Aaron No problem. `enums` are basically just fancy `ints`. They should only be iterated through during controlled situations like yours.

Answer (score 2):

As an alternative, you can use [Boost Assignment Library](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_39_0/libs/assign/doc/index.html).
Then you will get something like this:

```
#include <boost/assign/list_of.hpp>
#include <set>
class CreateAndUseIniFile {
public:
    enum iniFileValues {
        FIXED_VOLTAGE1,
        FIXED_VOLTAGE2,
        FIXED_VOLTAGE3,
        FIXED_VOLTAGE4
    };
    CreateAndUseIniFile() {
        m_modules =
            boost::assign::list_of
                (FIXED_VOLTAGE1)
                (FIXED_VOLTAGE2)
                (FIXED_VOLTAGE2)
                (FIXED_VOLTAGE3)
                (FIXED_VOLTAGE4);
    }
    std::set<CreateAndUseIniFile::iniFileValues> m_modules;
};
```